# Summing up the already summed up column based on a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

This is the result after summed up of Amount.
In the query the Amount column is already Summed up ( i.e  `SUM(InsAmt) AS Amount`)

```
PK      Amount     Code   Company
123     -528.00     OP      ABC
123      376.37     OP      ABC
124      123.87     KJ      BAK
124       84.76     KA      BAK
```

I want this be summed up again when Codes are same.

**Expected Output :**

```
PK      Amount     Code   Company
123     -151.63     OP      ABC
124      123.87     KJ      BAK
124       84.76     KA      BAK
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select PK, sum(Amount) as Amount, Code, Company  from table  group by PK, Code, Company
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always apply another `SUM` operation:

```
select PK, sum(Amount) as Amount, Code, Company
from [YourTable]
group by PK, Code, Company
```

But instead, I would suggest revisiting the original query and fixing its `GROUP` and `SUM` logic, which seems not to be providing the results you want. We won't be able to help with that, without seeing the original query.

Comment: This dataset is just a sample. I am pretty sure he has different values in the other 2 columns due to which the first query isnt able to produce what is being asked here.

Comment: No way to really know without further explanation, as you've pointed out above.